# After the initial meld, can I do multiple moves in the same turn?

Tags: rummikub

I have to code a program that suggests what to do depending on the situation of a Rummikub game. More about Rummikub: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummikub

In Wikipedia's explanation, I quote:

> Once a player has made his initial meld, he can, on each turn, **play one or more tiles** from his rack, making or adding to groups and/or runs.

I have never actually played Rummikub (and I seriously don't want to try the online multiplayer game), so here's my question: after the initial meld, if I can do multiple things (say, put a **Run** and also a **Group**), can I do them **both in the same turn**? Or am I limited to one "move" per turn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as much legal "moves" as you like in the same turn. After making the initial meld, rest of this player's turn is treated just like any other turn.

Things you can do in your turn (multiple times):

- add tile to existing group/run
- put set of tiles creating new group/run
- break existing set (group/run) into separate tiles, as long as all of them will be left on the table at the end of your turn, and each one will be part of some legal set.
- obtain Joker, by putting the tile it's replacing in the Joker's place on the table. Remember that you can't take any tiles from the table, so the Joker has to be used in some way before you finish your turn!

I know you said you're not interested in playing the game online, but this seems like the easiest way to grasp this. I feel that explanation like this is much more confusing.

If you want, please take a look at [official rules](http://www.rummikub.com/Themes/rummikub/info/Rummikub_Static_Pages/Rules.aspx).

Comment: Not me, Manipulations did ;). Glad I could help.